# How to obtain counts of the number of times a row changes from being above or below a critical value in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, subset, large-data

I have a data frame that I am working with that is a series of probabilities as output from an HMM. I want to know the number of times that the probability switches from being above an arbitrary critical value to being below that value and vice versa. I am very new to R, and while I developed a code that produces an output, it is rather time intensive.

```
> Haplo                         #Subset of original dataframe
chr2L_502618 chr2L_502999 chr2L_504449 chr2L_504509 chr2L_504686 chr2L_504688 chr2L_504690 chr2L_504706 chr2L_505918 chr2L_506002
3       0.04865      0.04864       0.0486       0.0486       0.0486       0.0486       0.0486       0.0486      0.04857      0.04856
4       0.04769      0.04767      0.04764      0.04764      0.04764      0.04764      0.04764      0.04764      0.04761       0.0476
5       0.04817      0.04817      0.04813      0.04813      0.04813      0.04813      0.04813      0.04813      0.04808      0.04807
6        0.0612      0.06118      0.06114      0.06114      0.06114      0.06114      0.06113      0.06113      0.06112      0.06112
7       0.41175      0.41178      0.41193      0.41194      0.41194      0.41194      0.41194      0.41194      0.41206       0.4121
8       0.04754      0.04752      0.04749      0.04749      0.04749      0.04749      0.04749      0.04749      0.04746      0.04745
9       0.27742      0.27742      0.27751      0.27751      0.27751      0.27751      0.27751      0.27751      0.27756      0.27759
10      0.05761       0.0576      0.05757      0.05757      0.05756      0.05756      0.05756      0.05756      0.05753      0.05753
11      0.00067      0.00065      0.00059      0.00059      0.00059      0.00059      0.00059      0.00059      0.00055      0.00053
12      0.00075      0.00073      0.00067      0.00067      0.00067      0.00067      0.00067      0.00067      0.00063      0.00061
> probs <- array(0,dim=dim(Haplo))
> for (i in 1:ncol(probs)) {probs[,i] <- as.character(Haplo[,i])}
> crits <- matrix(as.numeric(probs>0.27751),nrow=nrow(probs),ncol=ncol(probs))
> crits              
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

This gives me a data frame where any value above the critical value is a 1 and anything below is a 0, which I can then feed into a nested for loop to tell when a row changes from 0 to 1 or vice versa

```
> shifts <- c()
> for (g in 1:nrow(crits)){
+     for (i in 1:(ncol(crits)-1)){
+         shifts <- c(shifts, sapply(crits[g,i], identical, y=crits[g,i+1]))
+      }
+  }
> shifts2 <- matrix(as.numeric(!shifts), nrow=nrow(crits), ncol=(ncol(crits)-1), byrow=TRUE)
> shifts2                   #Times a column isn't identical to previous by row
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
> sums <- c()
> for (i in 1:nrow(shifts2)){
+      sums <- c(sums, sum(shifts2[i,]))
+      }
> sums
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

My problem is that while this generates the answer I am looking for (a vector of the sum of each rows shifts from above/below critical value) this takes too long on larger datasets. I have several sets of data frames that are all roughly 6,000 rows by 46,000 columns. I am aware that R is inefficient with for loops, but I am rather inexperienced with R and only slightly more with bash, being new to coding in general. Any help that can optimize this process would be much appreciated. Apologies if this question isn't formatted to standard or if it has been asked elsewhere, this is my first post and I wasn't able to find a solution on a previous ask.

**Update**
Small hypothetical data frame and expected output

```
          X1         X2         X3        X4         X5
1  0.9650217 0.07409232 0.22213328 0.3121305 0.31466359
2  0.1475712 0.06802015 0.63699272 0.2434809 0.17147398
3  0.2951922 0.65086116 0.09405872 0.2389092 0.10440221
4  0.6780534 0.73516696 0.62324000 0.9203979 0.89965700
5  0.4788420 0.16794910 0.13661247 0.5266925 0.52919389
6  0.6738885 0.68843836 0.17165125 0.2478758 0.94910386
7  0.8461378 0.74790781 0.16186888 0.8145674 0.13336087
8  0.3557357 0.65646290 0.21965522 0.6859082 0.55574490
9  0.5262744 0.74453676 0.18037489 0.2106494 0.01274704
10 0.9694096 0.41149759 0.03084501 0.8243646 0.42332927
critical_value=0.3
#expected output: 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2
```

To clarify, anytime {df[x,y]>crit_value & df[x,y+1]<=crit_value} or {df[x,y]<=crit_value & df[x,y+1]>crit_value}, I need a count so I can get the sum of sign changes relative to a given crit_value.

Comment: only value [5,3] is above, [7,3] is exactly equal and the rest are below. Picked the critical value based on this, for this subset, but it seems to work appropriately for any given value in testing.

Comment: @HowlArgwen Add a small data set (eg 10 rows x 5 columns) and show your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of thumb in R is that, if you want to write a fast code, you have to use R functions that are vectorized as opposed to loops. Based on my understanding of your problem, I wrote a function that delivers what you requested:

```
find_switch <- function(test_ds, crit_val){
 m <- sapply(test_ds, function(x) as.integer(x > crit_val))
 tm <- t(m)
 nrtm <- nrow(tm)
 colSums(tm - rbind(tm[1,], tm[1:(nrtm-1),]) != 0)
}
```

Observe that I use vectorized operations on matrices.

I wrapped your code into a function:

```
find_switch2 <- function(test_ds, crit_val){
  crits <- matrix(as.numeric(test_ds > crit_val),nrow=nrow(test_ds),ncol=ncol(test_ds))
  shifts <- c()
  for (g in 1:nrow(crits)){
    for (i in 1:(ncol(crits)-1)){
      shifts <- c(shifts, sapply(crits[g,i], identical, y=crits[g,i+1]))
      }
  }

  shifts2 <- matrix(as.numeric(!shifts), nrow=nrow(crits), ncol=(ncol(crits)-1), byrow=TRUE)

  sums <- c()
  for (i in 1:nrow(shifts2)){
    sums <- c(sums, sum(shifts2[i,]))
    }
  sums
}
```

and came up with some mock data set to benchmark two functions on:

```
set.seed(123)
n_row <- 5e2

crit_val <- 0.3

test_ds <- data.frame(p1 = runif(n_row),
                      p2 = runif(n_row),
                      p3 = runif(n_row),
                      p4 = runif(n_row))
```

The critical value was set to `0.3`.

Then I timed both implementations:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(find_switch(test_ds, crit_val), find_switch2(test_ds, crit_val))

 #Unit: microseconds expr       min         lq       mean    median         uq       max neval
 #find_switch(test_ds, crit_val)    96.265   121.8295   177.7687   176.132   206.4575   352.265   100
 #find_switch2(test_ds, crit_val) 27499.848 31556.8755 36564.2898 34315.394 40223.6580 93957.460   100
```

The difference in speed is **250 TIMES**. So, this is why it is important to use vectorized functions.

Finally, let's make sure the two functions produce identical output:

```
identical(find_switch(test_ds, 0.3), find_switch2(test_ds, 0.3))
```

Comment: I tried running your function on my original dataset. Your function appears to give me the number of times that the row exceeds the critical value. I am trying to tell the number of times it changes from exceeding to being below or vice versa. Verbally, if half the numbers are above or below the critical value in a row, I need to know if those are grouped in two blocks (i.e. for 100 values first 50 above then 50 below), or switch every value( above, below, above, below...x25), or something in between. I might be able to adapt with an ifelse function. Still, this had useful ideas, so thank you.

Comment: @HowlArgwen Include a small test data set (5 x 10) and its expected outout, and it will be easier for me to understand what you want

Comment: @HowlArgwen Please take a look at the test data set above and correct expected output if needed.

Comment: For your test data set the expected output should be: 1, 0, 0, 0, 1. I will attempt to create a dataset that illustrates what I need more clearly and post.

Comment: @HowlArgwen Can you explain why the output is 1 for row 1? Two elements (col 1 and col 2) cross the critical value of 0.3.

Comment: The actual data is nonindependent, such that the values slowly increase or decrease moving left to right. I need to know anytime an entire block of values stops being above or below a critical_value, regardless of how many actual values are in a block. Since row 1 starts below 0.3, then goes above without ever going back down, it gets 1. If it went back down it would be 2, regardless of how many actual elements that took.

Comment: @HowlArgwen Now I understand what was requested. Edited my post again. Observe what the difference in speed is.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
colSums(diff(t(as.matrix(df) > .3)) != 0)

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 2  2  2  0  2  2  3  2  1  2
```

Data:

```
df <- df <- read.table(text = "          X1         X2         X3        X4         X5
1  0.9650217 0.07409232 0.22213328 0.3121305 0.31466359
2  0.1475712 0.06802015 0.63699272 0.2434809 0.17147398
3  0.2951922 0.65086116 0.09405872 0.2389092 0.10440221
4  0.6780534 0.73516696 0.62324000 0.9203979 0.89965700
5  0.4788420 0.16794910 0.13661247 0.5266925 0.52919389
6  0.6738885 0.68843836 0.17165125 0.2478758 0.94910386
7  0.8461378 0.74790781 0.16186888 0.8145674 0.13336087
8  0.3557357 0.65646290 0.21965522 0.6859082 0.55574490
9  0.5262744 0.74453676 0.18037489 0.2106494 0.01274704
10 0.9694096 0.41149759 0.03084501 0.8243646 0.42332927", header = TRUE)
```